# converting ruby regex to swift regex

Tags: ruby, regex, swift

I've been using swift for 3 months now and am trying to convert a web app into iOS for practice and to progress my knowledge etc. After a bit of googling though, I am struggling to find an elegant way to perform the following functions in swift:

```
    def search_for_float(line)
        line.gsub!(',','.')
        line.scan(/(\d+[,.]\d+)/).flatten[0].to_f
    end

    def search_for_integer(line)
        line.gsub!(',','.')
        line.scan(/(\d+)/).flatten[0].to_i
    end

    def search_for_words(line)
        line.split(" ").select{|word|word.match(/([a-zA-Z])/)}.join(" ").capitalize
    end
```

Any help would be great as i'm struggling to find a basic tutorial that i can use to transfer my limited ruby knowledge across too.

Comment: Don't translate directly. Write down the steps of what your existing Ruby code does, in detail, each one, so that you have a global view of the data flow. Like: "1- Replace comma with dot. 2- Search for an expression, flatten the array of results, then... " etc. Then you can "think in Swift" and write the new Swift code which will follow the thought process you've written down.

Comment: Thanks for your help, the main part I'm struggling with is translating the regex. I've managed to find workarounds, thanks to your help, for the .split, .flatten functions etc but the regex i cant seem to figure out.

Comment: Ah, excellent news! You can lookup "NSRegularExpression" to replace your "scan". Note that you will have to escape backslashes, like `\\[([^\\]]+)\\]`, this is one notable difference.

Comment: amazing thank you. what do you mean by escape backslashes? e.g replace (/([a-zA-Z])/) for \\(\\[a-z][A-Z])? this i s where i get lost

Comment: I just meant that whenever there's `\ ` it should be actually `\\ ` for the regex strings in Swift. :)

Comment: oh right, perfect, thank you so much for your help and patience!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/127667/discussion-between-wayne-rumble-and-eric-aya).